# Cannot add new System Recording: Unable to connect to remote asterisk

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

I having an issue when adding a new system recording .wav file (Admin > System Recordings). When I click on the Submit button. I got this dialog:

```
There was an error, See the console for more details
```

So i look at the Console to get more details:

```
Object { status: false, message: "Unable to connect to remote asterisk (does /var/run/asterisk/asterisk.ctl exist?)\n [/var/lib/asterisk/sounds/test-1562945124914.wav.wav]" }
recordings.js:123:14
Unable to connect to remote asterisk (does /var/run/asterisk/asterisk.ctl exist?)
 [/var/lib/asterisk/sounds/test-1562945124914.wav.wav] recordings.js:139:13
```

This is what I have tried but cannot find out the solution:

- The file /var/run/asterisk/asterisk.ctl is 100% exists.
- Asterisk is running and working by make a call test.
- AMI is running by telnet to port 5038 for testing.
- service asterisk restart , systemctl restart httpd.service , reboot, re-install Recording module  ... does not help.

update:
I got the same issue when uploading file at Settings > Music On Hold.

```
Unable to connect to remote asterisk (does /var/run/asterisk/asterisk.ctl exist?)
File:/var/www/html/admin/libraries/media/Media/Driver/Drivers/AsteriskShell.php:170
```

Is this issue related to IPTables? Do I need to any rules to IPtables for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got an answer from here and it works:
https://community.freepbx.org/t/unable-to-connect-to-remote-asterisk/1620/2

```
Edit your asterisk.conf file…
nano /etc/asterisk/asterisk.conf

then add these lines to it…

[files]
astctlpermissions = 0660
astctlowner = asterisk
astctlgroup = pbx
astctl = asterisk.ctl
```